# New HttpSession When Using Chrome and Tomcat for each request

Tags: java, google-chrome, tomcat, httpsession

I created a basic login page which sets an attribute in the session object should the user login correctly and checks the value of this attribute for subsequent attempts to access 'secured' information.  When using Firefox and IE, this code works as expected; however, when using Chrome, each login attempt generates a new session object.  What configuration values should I add/modify to get Chrome to work?

I am deploying Tomcat 8 and using IIS/isapi_redirect.dll.

Comment: Are you using HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: I'm using HTTP.

Comment: Chrome has been making some changes lately with cookies when not using HTTPS. Can you switch to HTTPS and see if it still behaves in a surprising way?

Comment: Also, Tomcat will usually set the "secure=true" flag on any session cookies it creates. If you aren't using TLS, your HTTP BASIC logins *and* your session cookies are trivially vulnerable to anyone who wants them.